# Pass a function as a parameter to (click) event through Angular component

Tags: angular, input, components, selector

I'm trying to create a component with a cancel and send buttons to avoid c&p on each form but I can't find a way to pass functions as a parameter to the component selector

HTML:

```
<btn-submit [cancelFunction]='test' [acceptFunction]='test'></btn-submit>
```

TS Parent:

```
test = () => console.log("this is a test");
```

TS Child:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'btn-submit',
  styleUrls: ['./btn.component.scss'],
  template: `
          <button class="btn" click="cancelFunction()">
              <fa name="times"></fa>
          </button>
          <button class="btn" click="acceptFunction()">
              <fa name="check"></fa>
          </button>
  `
})

export class BtnSubmitComponent {
  @Input() cancelFunction: any;
  @Input() acceptFunction: any;
}
```

Comment: You should be using `Output` instead really

Comment: You are using event binding when I think you need to be using property binding. If you want to pass the functions *in* to the nested child component, you need the `Input` decorator, but need to bind it using property binding. Also, I think you want to pass in the function, not execute the function, so you may need to take the `()` off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to actually pass a function in from a parent component to a child component you can do it as shown in the code below.

But using the more common `@Output` and `EventEmitter` approach as shown in other answers may be a better option. The @Output technique does not let you pass in a function, but does allow your parent component to receive events from the child component that you can respond to by calling a function in the parent component.

Here is code that allows you to pass a function in from a parent component to a child component.

**Parent component**

```
test = () => console.log("this is a test");
```

**Parent template**

```
<pm-star [rating]='product.starRating'
    [testFunction]='test'
    (ratingClicked)='onRatingClicked($event)'>
</pm-star>
```

Notice the square brackets (property binding) and it does not *call* a function but rather binds to a property of the component containing the function.

**Child component**

```
  @Input() testFunction: any;
```

**Child template**

```
<div class="crop"
     [style.width.px]="starWidth"
     [title]="rating"
     (click)="testFunction()">
```

I have a stackblitz with a simple working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwguwk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't work now? I've just edited the OP. Tried C&P the code from stackblitz and it works correctly but mine doesn't

Comment: These need to use event binding: `(click)="cancelFunction()"` You are missing the parenthesis in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that was the main issue of my code since I did all the tests without binding click. I also tried with @user184994 example and it didn't work because of that

Comment: Thanks! works perfectly, and exactly what I looked for.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [@Output](https://angular.io/api/core/Output#output) decorator in conjunction with [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter#eventemitter) class to achieve this

Child component (Typescript and markup)

```
        import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

        @Component({
          selector: 'btn-submit',
          styleUrls: ['./btn.component.scss'],
          template: `
                  <button class="btn" click="cancelFunction()">
                      <fa name="times"></fa>
                  </button>
                  <button class="btn" click="acceptFunction()">
                      <fa name="check"></fa>
                  </button>
          `
        })

        export class BtnSubmitComponent {
          @Output() clicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
          cancelFunction(){
            this.clicked.emit("CANCELLED"); // Pass any payload as argument
          }
          acceptFunction{
            this.clicked.emit("ACCEPTED"); // Pass any payload as argument
          }
        }
```

Parent markup

```
<btn-submit (clicked)="onAddClicked($event)" [acceptFunction]='test'></btn-submit>
```

Parent Typescript function

```
onAddClicked(event: any){
console.log(event); // Your payload is in 'event'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it from `@Input` to `@Output`

```
@Output() acceptFunction = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Then, inside your component when you want to invoke it, do:

```
this.acceptFunction.emit();
```

The HTML can stay as is.

```
    <btn-submit (cancelFunction)="myCancelFunction()"
            (sendFunction)="mySendFunction()></btn-submit>
```

Each time you call `.emit()`, it will fire an event. The parent will hear this event, and call which function you've bound (e.g. `mySendFunction`)

Comment: What's the advantage of using Output in this case?

Comment: @prevox That's already explained in the answer by Deborah. Quoting here - "But using the more common @Output and EventEmitter approach as shown in other answers may be a better option. The `@Output` technique does not let you pass in a function, but does allow your parent component to receive events from the child component that you can respond to by calling a function in the parent component."